# A problem arising from Wiener-Levy theorem on the real line

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Theorem (Wiener-Levy). Let $A(\mathbb{T})$ be the Fourier-algebra on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$. Let $f$ be in $A(\mathbb{T})$ and suppose that $F$ is an analytic function on the range of $f$. Then $F\circ f$ is in $A(\mathbb{T})$.

Let $B(\mathbb{R})$ be the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra on the real line (which is the Fourier transform of $M(\mathbb{R})$, the space of all complex Radon Measures on the real line).

> Q.  Let $f$ be a function in $B(\mathbb{R})$. Let  $F$ be an analytic function on the range of $f$. Is $F\circ f$ in $B(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: The answer is yes even in a more general context. Please look for *functional calculus* in books about Banach algebras.